# How to add a comma in array.map after every element except last element in React JSX

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

How can I add a trailing comma after every element of an array for making a list like:

`INV, INV, INV, INV`

Note that the last element doesn't have a trailing comma

Currently iterating the list with `array.map`:

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map(function(item) {
          return <div>{item}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var data = ["red", "green", "blue"];

React.render(<List data={data} />, document.body);
```

Comment: you need a string in return?

Comment: You can try a simple hack: `array.map((item, index) => (<div>{ (index ? ', ': '') + item}</div>))`. What this will do is, check if index is valid, add a comma else blank string. And since 0 in JS is falsey, it will skip for 1st entry

Comment: `arr.join(',');`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Join will make it string and not Array<ReachNode>

Comment: Why do you need a trailing comma for

Comment: @Rajesh you're right if we need an array.

Comment: React render needs ReactNode or JSX. Not sure how it will interpret string. Also, since ReactNode is an object, it might return `"[object Object], [object Object]..."`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Want to display an inline list of titles like: `JavaScript, React, Angular`. It should be a string.

Comment: `data=data.map((x,i,arr)=>(i<arr.length-1)?x+',':x)`

Comment: @AjayGupta In that case, your code is incorrect. `Div` is a block element. Instead use a span or wrap everything in 1 div. In this case you can use Mohit's suggestion to use join

Comment: Dude just do .map and then .join.. example: array.map(c => c).join(',')

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As commented you can use:

> array.map((item, index) => ({ (index ? ', ': '') + item }))

Also, since you want to display text inline, using a div is not appropriate. Instead you can/should use an inline element like `span`

```js
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.data.map(function(item, index) {
            return <span key={`demo_snap_${index}`}>{ (index ? ', ' : '') + item }</span>;
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var data = ["red", "green", "blue"];

ReactDOM.render(<List data={data} />, demo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Remember to add a `key={index}` to the `<span>` or you'll get a warning in the console

Comment: Just came across this and I wanted to say thanks for this solution! I'm also wondering why does index ? ',':'' work? :) I don't understand the logic behind it, as index is just a number?

Comment: @SJ19 Since we are prepending value, we have to make sure we dont add extra comma. So for that I do that ternary operator. Since in JS `0` is falsey, for first iteration, nothing will be added

Comment: @Rajesh OH, I kept thinking the other way around, I was wondering how it knew we were on the last index. Now it makes sense. Thanks! Smart solution.

Comment: great! wanted such way.

Answer (score 9):

Use the CSS [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (`+`) to add pseudo element (`::before`) with a comma to all sibling items, but the 1st:

```js
const List = ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    {data.map((item, idx) => (
      <span className="item" key={idx}>{item}</span>
    ))}
  </div>
);

var data = ["red", "green", "blue"];

ReactDOM.render(<List data={data} />, demo);
```

```css
.item + .item::before {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre;
  content: ", ";
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Another option is to create a **generic** component that expects a list of items, and an optional separator, and maps the children to include the separator. This uses the index method detailed in [Rajesh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47882041/5157454).

**Note:** due to the old BabelJS version used by the SO snippet, I need to use `<Fragment>` instead of the shorter `<>` for a fragment.

```js
const { Children, Fragment } = React;

const AddSeparators = ({ children, separator = ', ' }) =>
  Children.map(children, (child, idx) => (
    <Fragment>
      {idx ? separator : ''}
      {child}
    </Fragment>
  ));

const List = ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <AddSeparators separator=" | ">
      {data.map((item, idx) => (
        <span key={idx}>{item}</span>
      ))}
    </AddSeparators>
  </div>
);

var data = ["red", "green", "blue"];

ReactDOM.render(<List data={data} />, demo);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Just an opinionated comment but I would prefer using JS instead. Also using a div and adding `display: inline-block` looks weird.

Comment: Why would you prefer JS in this case?

Comment: I prefer keeping UI changes to CSS and such manipulation to JS. Again, this is just my preference/opinion. Yes using CSS would be more performant, but it might reduce readability.

Comment: I actually considers this a part of the design, thus fitting for CSS. Why would it reduce readability? I'm interested in knowing your opinion :)

Comment: Why am I getting a feeling, this is one of those conversation where you say something incorrect and your friend instead of correcting you, would flow around and play with you for fun. :-p

Comment: But to answer, in my opinion, *what is to be rendered* should belong to HTML + JS and *how they should be shown* belongs to CSS. But I agree, I have a lot to understand.

Comment: @Rajesh - your feeling is incorrect in this case :) Pseudo elements and content are indeed a grey area. The question is - are the commas part of the content itself, or are they part of the design? And you can answer it both ways. I'm not sure about readability though. On one hand it might be confusing - "where is the comma coming from?". On the hand it reduces noise in the JSX, and a short inspect will show you where it comes form. So, as you stated - a matter of opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161509/discussion-between-ori-drori-and-rajesh).

Answer (score 9):

What you can do is, check the index of item, if index is not equals to the last item render the `,` otherwise nothing.

Write it like this:

```
{
    this.props.data.map((item, i, arr) => <span>{item} {i != (arr.length-1) ? ',' : ''}</span>)
}
```

You can also store the total data length in a separate variable and instead of checking the `arr.length` in each iteration check with that variable.

Working example:

```js
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
    this.props.data.map((item, i, arr) => <span>{item} {i != (arr.length-1) ? ', ' : ''}</span>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var data = ["red", "green", "blue"];

ReactDOM.render(<List data={data} />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const data = ["red", "green", "blue"];

class List extends React.Component{
render(){
return( 
<div>
{this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
  return <span>{ (index ? ', ' : '') + item }</span>;
})}
</div>
)
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<List data={data}/>,
document.getElementById('demo')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

just do it like this:

`<div>{array.join(',')}</div>`

Answer (score 2):

As specified by @toxxiczny we can use joins in javascript.

`array.join(', ');`

Answer (score 1):

try
`array.toString()`

you will get `INV, INV, INV, INV`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but this is BY FAR the easiest way without any functions. Works great in inline statements and requires no separate functions or mapping if that's what's needed in your case.

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log("Items: " + "" + items + ".")
```

The ""+ before the array adds the comma for some reason I don't fully understand why.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map(function(item) {
          return <div>{item.join(",")}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var data = ["red", "green", "blue"];

React.render(<List data={data} />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Comma + Natural word wrapping

Here's a way to do it while maintaining proper linebreaks with the comma.

```
['red', 'green', 'blue']
  .reduce((a, b, index) => [
    ...a,
    <Fragment key={`comma-${index}`}>{', '}</Fragment>,
    <Fragment key={`value-${index}`}>{b}</Fragment>
  ], [])
  .slice(1);
```

#### Why not group the comma in the `map` function?

In word-wrapping scenarios, the comma is attached to the following word, when it should be attached to the immediate left word.

#### Why not `[...a, ',', b]`?

React needs a `key` to map the proper item within the virtual DOM (to avoid repaints on re-render). Plus it won't throw a `key` warning on lower environments

#### Why is there `slice`?

Because of the 3rd argument of `reduce`, the first iteration always adds a comma. `slice(1)` shifts the array by 1. This also makes it easier to understand the code instead of adding a logic statement inside the reduce function.

#### Do I have to use `<Fragment />`?

You can use any component instead of `Fragment`, like a `span` or your custom component.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map(function(item) {
          return <div>{item.join(",")}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var data = ["red", "green", "blue"];

React.render(<List data={data} />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).